# Bugsnag: Missing function mergeWith when upgrading to version 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, bugsnag

My iOS is using [Bugsnag](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-cocoa) and I am trying to upgrade it from version 4.1.0 to version 5.

The new SDK breaks a function that was available in version 4.x:

```
[[[Bugsnag configuration] metaData] mergeWith:parameters];
```

Where *parameters* is of type `NSDictionary`.

I couldn't find any substitute in the SDK, besides:

```
- (void)addAttribute:(NSString*)attributeName withValue:(id)value toTabWithName:(NSString*)tabName
```

But it does not provide the same functionality where `value` could be a `NSDictionary` itself. Moreover, it will also invoke `[self.delegate metaDataChanged:self]` on every addition (highly inefficient).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking in the [Github repository](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-cocoa) and seeing the difference in `BugsnagMetaData` between the versions, I found a way to restore this functionality. I wrote a category that extends the class:

```
@interface BugsnagMetaData (BugsnagExtension)

- (void)mergeWith:(NSDictionary *)data;

@end

@implementation BugsnagMetaData (BugsnagExtension)

- (void)mergeWith:(NSDictionary *)data {
    @synchronized(self) {
        NSString *customDataKey = @"customData";
        [data enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id value, BOOL *stop) {
            NSMutableDictionary *destination = [self getTab:customDataKey];
            if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                NSDictionary *source = value;
                [source enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id sourceKey, id sourceValue, BOOL *stop) {
                    if ([destination objectForKey:sourceKey] && [sourceValue isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                        [[destination objectForKey:sourceKey] mergeWith:(NSDictionary *)sourceValue];
                    } else {
                        [destination setObject:sourceValue forKey:sourceKey];
                    }
                }];

            } else {
                [destination setObject:value forKey:key];
            }
        }];

        [self.delegate metaDataChanged:self];
    }
}

@end
```

This function is able to accept NSDictionary that contains NSDictionary like before, and calls `[self.delegate metaDataChanged:self]` efficiently only when needed.